# Getting the Value of a Static GameObject with Different Values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static-members

I'm currently creating a quest system for my game in Unity3D. It has a working quest system so far for now and it looks like this:

[image]

And after killing the specific monster for that quest, the value of the quest incremented:

[image]

But if I take other quest for example like this:

[image]

[image]

You can see that the values didn't increment unlike in what I did in the first one, even though the conditions are met. What I did here is that on my NPC (Non-player Character) I've attached a script called QuestGiver and on my player, I've attach a script called QuestTracker. on my QuestTracker, I've connect it to my QuestGiver for it to be accessed anywhere, because I have many NPC.

```
public static QuestGiver questGiver;
```

Now, on my QuestGiver, here is my code:

```
public string mobName;    
    void Update ()
        {
            if (fighter.opponent != null && killQuest)
            {
                if (mobToBeKilled.mobName == mobName && questAccepted)
                {
                    if (mobToBeKilled.isDead() && !mobToBeKilled.isAlive && !questFinish)
                    {
                        currentKillCount++;
                        mobToBeKilled.isAlive = true;

                        if (currentKillCount == maxKillCount)
                        {
                            questFinish = true;
                            log.logText.text = log.InitialValue + questTitle + " quest completed!\n";
                            log.NewValue = log.logText.text;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see on my inspector, I've set the name for the monster to be killed on the string called mobName and the static variable on my QuestTracker can be accessed by a method on my QuestGiver:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    QuestTracker.questGiver = this;
}
```

For me to access the mobToBeKilled, I've attach a OnMouseEnter() function on my enemy script which is this:

```
private void OnMouseEnter()
{
    player.GetComponent<Fighter>().opponent = gameObject;
    QuestGiver.mobToBeKilled = this;
}
```

I can say that this is working fine as I for example Debug.Log(mobToBeKilled.mobName) and it output either "Dragon" or "Killer Bee". But when I Debug.Log(mobName), which will be supposed to be the one that the NPC will request to target, it output 2 names, which you can see in the console on the image. Is it possible that I can access this static object with 2 different values? Sorry for the long post, I just want to clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

There are cleary more than one GameObject running the `Debug.Log()` command.
Also, `mobName` is the name of the mob itself, that's why it outputs a different value for each GameObject that is doing the `Debug.Log()`.